# ibm java on rhel 7.4 is so slow

Tags: java, performance, websphere, rhel7

I am trying to install IBM Installation Manager(agent.installer.linux.gtk.x86_64_1.9.0.20190715_0328.zip) on Rhel 7.4 which is installed newly. I test the java because GUI is so slow and here are the result; as you can see oracle java dramaticly faster than IBM java!! why does this happen?

```
[root@adige bin]# uname -a
Linux adige 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 6 19:56:57 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@adige bin]# time /installations/unpacked/installationManagerX86_64_1.9/jre_8.0.5035.20190626_1229/jre/bin -version
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.0.5.35 - pxa6480sr5fp35-20190418_01(SR5 FP35))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.9, JRE 1.8.0 Linux amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20190417_414854 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 777635f
OMR      - 16b77d7
IBM      - 72459d3)
JCL - 20190409_01 based on Oracle jdk8u211-b25

real    0m20.185s    <<<<<< Lasting 20 seconds.
user    0m0.169s
sys 0m0.034s


[root@adige bin]# time /tmp/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

real    0m0.098s
user    0m0.079s
sys 0m0.031s
```

Comment: I have the same experience. I think it is a problem of the IBM Java. We have no source, no updates - I think we can leave the project as it is, and use the distro-builtin JDK or adoptopenjdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem caused by hostname is not in DNS records and /etc/hosts does not contain hostname. You can find the solution at this site. I did not link because ibm sunsetting community sites through developerworks. 
 https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=7becc2aa-6897-4d16-b696-dca2c9e767bf

Answer (score 0):

That's very strange. real and user times would normally be very similar on a lightly loaded system. e.g.

```
$ time bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.0.5.36 - pxa6480sr5fp36-20190510_01(SR5 FP36))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.9, JRE 1.8.0 Linux amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20190502_415899 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 46e57f9
OMR      - 06a046a
IBM      - 0b909bf)
JCL - 20190409_01 based on Oracle jdk8u211-b25

real    0m0.090s
user    0m0.093s
sys 0m0.012s
```

I've not heard of any similar issues with IBM Java on RHEL. Is there any possibility that the filesystem where /installations/unpacked/installationManagerX86_64_1.9 is mounted is having problems?

Comment: actually /installation not a seperated file system. And i also copy installation manager to /tmp folder and result is same. We back to RHEL 6.2 for now.

Comment: The problem happens on RHEL 7.4 but not 6.2?

Comment: I just re-tested on one of our RHEL 7.4 machines, but I can't reproduce the problem: 
`real 0m0.118s user 0m0.093s sys 0m0.053s`